# Is there a compiler flag to skip a compile source on simulator?

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, ios-simulator, conditional-statements, compiler-flags

As the title goes.
I'm aware of...

```
#if (TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
    #import "CameraViewController_simulator.h"
#else
    #import "CameraViewController_device.h"
#endif
```

...like solution, but I'd love a **compiler only solution** (if there is any). Like `-fno-objc-arc` marks non ARC sources.